# android ble readCharacteristic take a long time

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use bluetoothle sample (android-sdks/samples/android-18/legacy/BluetoothLeGatt/) on new nexus 7 (4.3 JSS15R) to test bluetooth. And I found readCharacteristic spend too much time (about 1 ~ 3 seconds for each read).

First, I trigger readCharacteristic when services item clicked.

```
    DeviceControlActivity.java
    ....
    private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner = 
    ....
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
    ....
         mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Then I repeat the readCharacteristic when characteristic is read.

```
    BluetoothLeService.java
    ....
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if(TEST_COUNT < 20) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onCharacteristicRead");
            readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            TEST_COUNT ++; 
        } else {
            TEST_COUNT = 0;
        }   

        /*  
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
        */
    }
```

And log shows :

```
10-29 11:16:37.360: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:39.362: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:41.364: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:43.356: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:45.358: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:47.340: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:49.342: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:51.334: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:53.336: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:55.328: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:57.319: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:16:59.311: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:01.313: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:03.305: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:05.297: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:07.289: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:09.291: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:11.283: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:13.285: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:17:15.277: DEBUG/MyTest(9554): onCharacteristicRead
```

It takes 2 seconds to receive every characteristic read, really weird.

I test the same behaviour on galaxy s4 with samsung ble sdk and of course the same ble device. But the log shows it spend less time to read.

```
10-29 11:51:19.393  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:19.493  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:19.588  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:19.688  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:19.783  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:19.878  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:19.978  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.078  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.183  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.323  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.418  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.518  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.613  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.713  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.808  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:20.908  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:21.003  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:21.103  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:21.248  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:21.343  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
10-29 11:51:21.443  I/MyTest﹕  onCharacteristicRead
```

Is any one meet the same issue? is it cause by new nexus 7 hardware ? or android 4.3 sdk?

What should I do to reduce the time spend on readCharacteristic?

Comment: Review the log from all Android system(e.g. in Eclipse  LogCat - SavedFilters - All messages). There you can see what exactly happenned with app.

Comment: After some study, I finally found this behaviour is base on connections between peripheral and central. Modify the peripheral's connection interval can improve this.

Comment: Sam blood Kao - can you explain how?